# Reactor Flux replay(int history) method not working as expected

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm trying to make an example of a `Flux` with Project Reactor that has the following characteristics:

- A single hot observable, which emits one item per second.
- Two subscribers, each of them using a separate thread of the publisher.
- A limited history when calling `replay()`, so some items will be missed in case one of the subscribers is too slow.

Then I coded this sample:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import reactor.core.publisher.ConnectableFlux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class FluxTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ConnectableFlux<Integer> publisher = Flux.range(1, 20)
      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      .replay(8);

    publisher.publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("fast"))
      .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println("Fast subscriber - Received " + i);
        sleep(1);
      });

    publisher.publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("slow"))
      .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println("Slow subscriber - Received " + i);
        sleep(5);
      });

    publisher.connect();
  }

  private static void sleep(int seconds) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000L);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#replay-int-) of `replay(int history)` method, I'd expect that, after few seconds, the second consumer (the slow one) would start losing the track, but it doesn't. See this part of the console output as an example:

```
...
Fast subscriber - Received 14
Fast subscriber - Received 15
Slow subscriber - Received 4
Fast subscriber - Received 16
Fast subscriber - Received 17
```

I expected the slow subscriber not to be able to receive `4` since that element should no longer be in history (15 - 8 = 7, that should be the last one).

Note that, if I use the method `replay(8, Duration.ofSeconds(8))` then I get what I'd expect:

```
...
Fast subscriber - Received 14
Fast subscriber - Received 15
Slow subscriber - Received 8
Fast subscriber - Received 16
Fast subscriber - Received 17
```

I think I'm missing something important here, but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replay(8)` is capable of *replaying 8 elements that where emitted **before** the subscriber subscribed*. For elements that come in after, they are directly relayed to the subscriber. Here you subscribe `slow` before you connect, so the size of the replay buffer doesn't really matter.

Your slow subscriber sleeps on a dedicated thread, so what happens is that `publishOn` does receive all of the data, puts it in an internal `Queue` and schedules itself on the `slow` thread to drain that queue, in a drain loop that gets blocked for 5s on each iteration.

Still, the operator has seen and is capable of processing all of the data.

Comment: Thanks Simon, that's what I was missing indeed. Anyways, I think the docs are a bit misleading:

`replay(int history)`: _Will retain up to the given history size onNext signals._

`replay(int history, Duration ttl)`: _Will retain up to the given history size onNext signals with a per-item ttl._

I would expect the latter to behave similarly and retain only the items before the next subscriber subscribes, but it's actually doing what I expected and setting a ttl on a per-item basis, thus causing the slow subscriber to miss items even though it subscribed at the same time.