# How to use a dedicated buffer per subscriber in Project Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I'm trying to create a sample project using Project Reactor and a scenario like the following:

- A publisher based on a hot source, which generates an item per second.
- Two subscribers (on separate threads): one being able to keep the pace of the hot observable, the other one being so slow that elements need to be buffered.
- A dedicated and configurable-in-size buffer per subscriber. Once the buffer is full, elements are dropped.

In Java 9, [this is possible](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SubmissionPublisher.html) using the class `SubmissionPublisher`:

> "Buffering allows producers and consumers to transiently operate at
>   different rates. Each subscriber uses an independent buffer. Buffers
>   are created upon first use and expanded as needed up to the given
>   maximum."

I'm basing my example on this sample code, in which I'm trying to apply the conditions described above:

```
import java.time.Duration;

import reactor.core.publisher.ConnectableFlux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers;

public class FluxTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ConnectableFlux<Integer> publisher = Flux.range(1, 20)
      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
      .replay(8);

    publisher.publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("fast"))
      .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println("Fast subscriber - Received " + i);
        sleep(1);
      });

    publisher.publishOn(Schedulers.newSingle("slow"))
      .subscribe(i -> {
        System.out.println("Slow subscriber - Received " + i);
        sleep(5);
      });

    publisher.connect();
  }

  private static void sleep(int seconds) {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000L);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This doesn't achieve the goal since the items are buffered anyway. The size of the buffer only applies before the next subscriber subscribes.

**How can I get independent buffering and drops per subscriber using Project Reactor's Flux?**

Note 1: I asked a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613775/reactor-flux-replayint-history-method-not-working-as-expected) but, in that case, the question only refers to a method.

Note 2: If you're curious, I'm trying to code [this example](https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2018/01/31/reactive-programming-java-9-flow/) in Project Reactor, but I'm struggling with it.